# Exclude list of words in Express.js route

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, express

I have something like this in Express.js Framework

app.post('/:username/:slug', user.fn);

Now I want to come up with a regular expression that checks if slug is equal to certain words (profile, album, etc.) , pass to the next route and don't capture the slug and username.

any ideas ?

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204513/catch-all-root-level-routing-in-express-js-considerations-and-reserving-possibl) related question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just put the more specific routes first:

```
app.post('/:username/profile', middlware)
app.post('/:username/album', middleware)
app.post('/:username/:slug', middleware)
```

But then again, I don't know what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: Thank you. For now I did just that. I have separated my routes in different files, and to keep the above order I had to mess around with couple of route files. That's why I was trying to figure a regular expression to exclude some words in a route as a more general approach to this kind of problem.

Comment: you can add regular expressions to the variables like `app.post('/:username(jon|jack)/:slug', middleware)` but I'm not sure what is and isn't supported as I haven't tested it with anything but an enumerated list of valid values

Comment: and i don't think it's documented